# DRY-rest-permissions somehow does not check my object permissions except global permissions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, permissions

I have recently started implementing dry-rest-permissions, but I can't seem to get it to check the `has_object_permissions`, it appears that only the global permissions work for me.

I am fairly new to implementing permissions and this is my first time implementing DRY-rest-permissions and have only recently started coding in django rest framework, so apologies for the lack of knowledge in advance.

At the moment I am trying to delete a company object by simply having a user call a URL, that URL then gets the current user's `active_company` and then deletes it only if the current `user` is the `active_company`'s `company_owner`.

But what I discovered, is that I somehow can't get `has_object_permissions` to work anywhere?

I have noticed that if I delete `has_write_permission(request)`, and hit the `company_delete` URL it gives me the following error:

`'<class 'company.models.Company'>' does not have 'has_write_permission' or 'has_company_delete_permission' defined.`

This means that it doesn't even look for the `has_object_company_delete_permission`. Meaning it only checks the global permissions rather than any of the object permissions, what am I possibly doing wrong here?

**My model:**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company_orders = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    company_icon = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='media/company_icon', blank=True)
    company_owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    company_employees = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, blank=True, null=True, related_name="company_employees")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name

    @staticmethod
    def has_write_permission(request):
        return False

    def has_object_company_delete_permission(self, request):
        return self.company_owner == request.user
```

**My views**

```
class CompanyView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):  # made for viewing details
    permission_classes = (DRYPermissions, )
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer

    def create(self, request):
        try:

            company_name = request.data['company_name']
            company_orders = request.data['company_orders']
            company_owner = request.data['company_owner']
            company_owner_obj = User.objects.get(id=company_owner)
            company = Company(company_name=company_name,
                              company_orders=company_orders, company_owner=company_owner_obj)
            company.save()

        except Exception as error:
            response = {
                'error': str(error)
            }
            return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        response = {
            'message': 'Company created'
        }

        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    def company_details(self, request):
        try:
            company_id = request.user.active_company.id

            company = Company.objects.get(id=company_id)

            serialized_data = CompanySerializer(company)

        except Exception as error:
            response = {
                'error': str(error)
            }
            return Response(response)

        return Response(serialized_data.data)

    def company_edit(self, request, **kwargs):
        try:
            company_id = request.user.active_company.id
            company = Company.objects.get(id=company_id)
            serializer = CompanySerializer(
                company, data=request.data, partial=True)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
        except Exception as error:
            response = {
                'message': str(error)
            }
            return Response(response)
        response = {
            'message': 'Edited Successfully'
        }
        return Response(response)

    def company_delete(self, request):
        try:
            company_id = request.user.active_company.id
            company = Company.objects.filter(id=company_id)
            company.delete()
        except Exception as error:
            response = {
                'message': str(error)
            }
            return Response(response)
        response = {
            'message': 'Deleted Successfully'
        }
        return Response(response)
```

**My urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
    #    Company URLs
    path('company_create/',
         CompanyView.as_view({'post': 'create'}), name='company_create'),  # Create company
    path('company_edit/',
         CompanyView.as_view(), name='company_edit'),  # Edit company details
    path('company_delete/',
         CompanyView.as_view({'delete': 'company_delete'}), name='company_delete'),  # Delete company
    path('company_details/',
         CompanyView.as_view({'get': 'company_details'}), name='company_details'),  # get company details (owner, employees etc)
]
```

**My serializer**

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company_owner = LimitedUserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ['id', 'company_name', 'company_orders',
                  'company_icon', 'company_owner']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that it somehow does not check for object permissions in any of my custom actions, thus adding the following check in either the get_object() or the custom action itself fixes this.

```
self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obtainedObject)
```

An example of what it looks like in my code:

```
@action(detail=True, methods=['patch'], pk=None)
def company_edit(self, request, **kwargs):
    try:
        company_id = request.user.active_company.id
        company = Company.objects.get(id=company_id)
        serializer = CompanySerializer(
            company, data=request.data, partial=True)
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, company)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
    except Exception as error:
        response = {
            'message': str(error)
        }
        return Response(response)
    response = {
        'message': 'Edited Successfully'
    }
    return Response(response)
```

Answer (score 2):

As described in [this part of the documentation](https://github.com/FJNR-inc/dry-rest-permissions#global-vs-object-permissions) the Global permissions are always checked first and Object permissions are checked ONLY if global permissions pass.

*Documentation Source:*

```
DRY Rest Permissions allows you to define both global and object level permissions.

Global permissions are always checked first and define the ability of a user to take an action on an entire model. For example you can define whether a user has the ability to update any projects from the database.

Object permissions are checked if global permissions pass and define whether a user has the ability to perform a specific action on a single object. These are also known as row level permissions. Note: list and create actions are the only standard actions that are only global. There is no such object level permission call because they are whole table actions.
```

---

In this context you have multiple problem actually that you should correct:

- Make sure `has_write_permission` return `True` for all users that own their active companies
- Make sure to rename `has_object_company_delete_permission` since we don't need the name of the model inside the function name

Example:

```
   @staticmethod
   def has_write_permission(request):
       # Everybody can create/update/delete if no specific rule says otherwise
       return True

   def has_object_delete_permission(self, request):
       # Only owner can delete
       return self.company_owner == request.user

   def has_object_update_permission(self, request):
       # Only owner can update
       return self.company_owner == request.user
```

Output:

- Everybody can create
- Only owner can update
- Only owner can delete

---

I know that it seems a little bit overkill just to delete an object, but with some experience it allow you to clearly define ans setup permission but also to easily share the generic rules with the Frontend by using `DryPermissionsField` and `DRYGlobalPermissionsField`

PS: This answer came from [my origin answer on Github](https://github.com/FJNR-inc/dry-rest-permissions/issues/23) to allow people finding a solution easily from StackOverFlow